# Float error not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I have a program that makes various calculations based on text provided in a text file. I get an error after the second entry is printed (the first works fine.)

The entry in the file is parsed to be a list:

```
['Castro, Starlin', 'CHC', '161', '666', '59', '163', '34', '2', '10']
```

I then make a call to the singles function, which takes four arguments.

```
singles = singles(float(line[5]),float(line[6]),float(line[7]),float(line[8]))
print "Singles: %s" % singles
```

The function is as follows:

```
def singles(a,b,c,d):
    # a = hits b = doubles c = triples d = homeruns
    # hits - (doubles + triples + homeruns)
    tmp1 = b + c + d
    return a - float(tmp1)
```

This works fine for the first entry:

```
['Machado, Manny', 'BAL', '156', '667', '88', '189', '51', '3', '14']
```

and the calculation successfully completes. However, the second is unable to complete:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\bhmfp\ian.carroll$\Intro to Computer Programming\Project 3\Project 3\main.py", line 107, in <module>
    singles = singles(float(line[5]),float(line[6]),float(line[7]),float(line[8]))
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: Do you define a variable named `float` or `singles` somewhere?

Comment: @VincentSavard I define singles as shown in the second code block.

Comment: move all float inside the definition of "singles" and avoid using the same name for a variable and for a function. Also, try to pass "line" instead of separate elements. This might help

Comment: @VincentSavard: `singles = singles(...)`.

Answer (score 7):

When you call

```
singles = singles(float(line[5]),float(line[6]),float(line[7]),float(line[8]))
```

You replace the function `singles` with the `float` returned by that function when it is called. Any subsequent calls to `singles` will try to call *that number, not the function*, and thus fail. Use a different name for the `return` value:

```
new_single = singles(*map(float, line[5:9]))
```

(Note use of `map`, slicing and unpacking to simplify the call.)

Comment: If the singles value is not required further, you can just `print('Singles: {}'.format(singles(*map(float, line[5:9]))))`